# Echo Mysql into a table - presentation and DOM

Tags: php, html, mysql

Two questions in one:
First question, mainly about presentation:
I'm echo-ing the following code which should create a table. The table should have a single column, but it's being rendered with the elements above the image as a single line. can anyone see why?

```
<?php   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catdata WHERE featured='yes' LIMIT 2";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['manufacturer'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr";

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr";

            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td><img src=\"6.diesel.png\"></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "l</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['mileage'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['fitsmodel'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr class=\"tablePriceBlock\">";
                echo "<td>£" . $row['pricefitted'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>£" . $row['pricedel'] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
            }
} else{
            echo "ERROR: Unable to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
?>
```

Question 2:

Can I show the second result in a second column, or as a separate table? Also, is it possible to access the `$result` elements like say, `$[manufacturer][1]`?

Comment: You are missing the closing ">" on your "</tr" tags. They should be "</tr>"

Answer (score 0):

Always look at the emitted source your code generates by either "View Source" or using a tool like `curl`. You'll find this mistake:

```
echo "</tr";
```

You're missing a `>`.

Many people who write HTML have browser plugins that can link through to an HTML validator to ensure they've got the correct syntax. You may want to find and install one of these.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the second result is a separate table follow the following code.

```
   echo "<table>";
                            $count = 1;
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if($count == 2){
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>put your code here</td>";
  echo "</tr>"
  echo </table>  

   }else{
                         echo "<tr>";
                         echo "<td>" . $row['manufacturer'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr";

                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr";

                            echo "<tr>";

                                echo "<td><img src=\"6.diesel.png\"></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                            echo "<tr>";    
                                echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "l</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['mileage'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['fitsmodel'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<tr class=\"tablePriceBlock\">";
                                echo "<td>£" . $row['pricefitted'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>£" . $row['pricedel'] . "</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
 }
$count ++;
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
```

As you are limiting your  query to only two record so this method is not bad for that and hope this will help.